# Terraform Loop with Range

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to loop through a range or list for a variable in terraform.

Below is what I would like to accomplish but I am not sure how to do it.

```
module "vlan_list" {
  depends_on  = [module.vlan_pools]
  source      = "../modules/add_vlans"
   vlan_list = {
      for i in range(1,100): {
        "access" = {
          vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["access"]
          from        = i
          to          = i
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Let me add more information to it because unfortunately that didn't work.  I get:

```
Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on pools_vlan.tf line 34, in module "vlan_list":
  34:    vlan_list = {
  35:       for i in range(1, 100):
  36:         "access" => {
  37:           vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["access"]
  38:           from        = i
  39:           to          = i
  40:         }...
  41:    }

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "vlan_list" defined
at ../modules/add_vlans/variables.tf:5,1-21: element "access": object
required.
```

So I have created a module with the following

```
resource "aci_ranges" "add_vlan" {
  for_each      = local.vlan_list
  alloc_mode    = each.value["alloc_mode"]
  annotation    = each.value["annotation"]
  name_alias    = each.value["name_alias"]
  vlan_pool_dn  = each.value["vlan_pool"]
  role          = each.value["role"]
  from          = "vlan-${each.value["from"]}"
  to            = "vlan-${each.value["to"]}"
}
```

From Here I have defined a variables file to make it so users don't have to enter every variable... they can accept defaults

```
terraform {
  experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
}

variable "vlan_list" {
  description = "Add VLANs to VLAN Pools"
  type = map(object({
    alloc_mode  = optional(string)
    annotation  = optional(string)
    from        = optional(number)
    name_alias  = optional(string)
    role        = optional(string)
    to          = optional(number)
    vlan_pool   = optional(string)
  }))
}

locals {
  vlan_list = {
    for k, v in var.vlan_list : k => {
      alloc_mode  = coalesce(v.alloc_mode, "static")
      annotation  = (v.annotation != null ? v.annotation : "")
      from        = (v.from != null ? v.from : 1)
      name_alias  = (v.name_alias != null ? v.name_alias : "")
      role        = coalesce(v.role, "external")
      to          = coalesce(v.to, 1)
      vlan_pool   = (v.vlan_pool != null ? v.vlan_pool : "")
    }
  }
}
```

So what I shared above is what someone would enter to consume the module... Here is a more complete example that I would like to do:

```
module "vlan_list" {
  depends_on  = [module.vlan_pools]
  source      = "../modules/add_vlans"
   vlan_list = {
      for i in range(1, 100):
        "access" => {
          vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["access"]
          from        = i
          to          = i
        }...
      for i in ranges([1000-1200], [1300-1400]):
        "vmm_dynamic" => {
          alloc_mode  = "dynamic"
          vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["vmm_dynamic"]
          from        = i
          to          = i
        }...
      for i in list[4, 100, 101]:
        "l3out" => {
          vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["l3out"]
          from        = i
          to          = i
        }...
   }
}
```

I know the second range on the vmm_dynamic key is not correct at all... I am just trying to show what I would like to be able to do if possible.

When the resource creates the entries, from the API, if I do it in a range as shown below; if someone needed to change the range for the first pool (in example) to 1-50,52-99, it would delete the entry and re-create it.  whereas if they are creating the entry with each entry being created individually it wouldn't delete all of the individual entries, optimally.

I can do the following and it works fine... but being able to add the VLANs individually from a loop would be preferable.

```
module "vlan_list" {
  depends_on  = [module.vlan_pools]
  source      = "../modules/add_vlans"
  vlan_list = {
    "access" = {
      vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["access"]
      from        = 1
      to          = 99
    },
    "vmm_dynamic" = {
      alloc_mode  = "dynamic"
      vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["vmm_dynamic"]
      from        = 1000
      to          = 1199
    },
    "l3out_1" = {
      vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["l3out"]
      from        = 4
      to          = 4
    },
    "l3out_2" = {
      vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["l3out"]
      from        = 100
      to          = 101
    },
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help on this.

Just as one more point of reference... This is how  I had previously accomplished this with Python, but I am trying to move this to native Terraform

```
def vlan_list_full(vlan_list):
    full_vlan_list = []
    if re.search(r',', str(vlan_list)):
        vlist = vlan_list.split(',')
        for v in vlist:
            if re.fullmatch('^\\d{1,4}\\-\\d{1,4}$', v):
                a,b = v.split('-')
                a = int(a)
                b = int(b)
                vrange = range(a,b+1)
                for vl in vrange:
                    full_vlan_list.append(vl)
            elif re.fullmatch('^\\d{1,4}$', v):
                full_vlan_list.append(v)
    elif re.search('\\-', str(vlan_list)):
        a,b = vlan_list.split('-')
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        vrange = range(a,b+1)
        for v in vrange:
            full_vlan_list.append(v)
    else:
        full_vlan_list.append(vlan_list)
    return full_vlan_list

def vlan_pool
    for z in range(1, 3):
        vgroup = 'VLAN_Grp%s' % (z)
        vgrp = 'VGRP%s_Allocation' % (z)
        templateVars['Allocation_Mode'] = templateVars[vgrp]
        if re.search(r'\d+', str(templateVars[vgroup])):
            vlan_list = vlan_list_full(templateVars[vgroup])
            for v in vlan_list:
                vlan = str(v)
                if re.fullmatch(r'\d+', vlan):
                    templateVars['VLAN_ID'] = int(vlan)

                    # Add VLAN to VLAN Pool File
                    create_tf_file('a+', dest_dir, dest_file, template, **templateVars)
```

I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this without Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I recently accomplished what I asked above.  It was about a year to figure it out but this is the way I could accomplish it.

```
# Map of Object input Variables is as shown below

variable "vlan_pools" {
  default = {
    "default" = {
      alias           = ""
      allocation_mode = "dynamic"
      description     = ""
      encap_blocks = {
        "default" = {
          allocation_mode = "inherit"
          description     = ""
          role            = "external"
          vlan_range      = "**REQUIRED**"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  description = <<-EOT
  key - name of the VLAN Pool
    * alias: A changeable name for a given object. While the name of an object, once created, cannot be changed, the alias is a field that can be changed.
    * allocation_mode: The allocation mode. The values can be:
      - dynamic (default): Managed internally by the APIC to allocate VLANs for endpoint groups (EPGs). A vCenter Domain can associate only to a dynamic pool.
      - static: One or more EPGs are associated with a domain, and that domain is associated with a static range of VLANs. You must configure statically deployed EPGs within that range of VLANs.
      When you create VLAN ranges, you can also assign the allocation mode to be inherited from the parent.
    * description: Description to add to the Object.    The description can be up to 128 alphanumeric characters.
    * encap_blocks:
      - allocation_mode: The allocation mode. The values can be:
        * dynamic: Managed internally by the APIC to allocate VLANs for endpoint groups (EPGs). A vCenter Domain can associate only to a dynamic pool.
        * inherit (default): The inherited mode from the parent device.
        * static: One or more EPGs are associated with a domain, and that domain is associated with a static range of VLANs. You must configure statically deployed EPGs within that range of VLANs.
      - description: Description to add to the Object.    The description can be up to 128 alphanumeric characters.
      - role: Role of the VLAN range. The options are:
        * external (Default): Used for allocating VLANs for each EPG assigned to the domain. The VLANs are used when packets are sent to or from leafs.
        * Internal: Used for private VLAN allocations in the internal vSwitch by the Cisco ACI Virtual Edge (AVE). The VLANs are not seen outside the ESX host or on the wire.
      - vlan_range: single vlan; i.e. 1.  range of vlans; i.e. 1-5. Or List of Vlans; i.e. 1-5,10-15
  EOT
  type = map(object(
    {
      alias           = optional(string)
      allocation_mode = optional(string)
      description     = optional(string)
      encap_blocks = map(object(
        {
          allocation_mode = optional(string)
          description     = optional(string)
          role            = optional(string)
          vlan_range      = string
        }
      ))
    }
  ))
}

# Which I then run some conditional modifications in locals to format the variables.

locals {
  #__________________________________________________________
  #
  # VLAN Pools Variables
  #__________________________________________________________

  # This first loop is to handle optional attributes and return 
  # default values if the user doesn't enter a value.

  vlan_pools = {
    for k, v in var.vlan_pools : k => {
      alias           = v.alias != null ? v.alias : ""
      allocation_mode = v.allocation_mode != null ? v.allocation_mode : "dynamic"
      description     = v.description != null ? v.description : ""
      encap_blocks    = v.encap_blocks != null ? v.encap_blocks : {}
    }
  }

  # Loop 1 is to determine if the encap_blocks are:
  # A Single number 1
  # A Range of numbers 1-5
  # A List of numbers 1-5,10-15
  # And then to return these values as a list

  vlan_ranges_loop_1 = flatten([
    for key, value in local.vlan_pools : [
      for k, v in value.encap_blocks : {
        allocation_mode = v.allocation_mode != null ? v.allocation_mode : "inherit"
        description     = v.description != null ? v.description : ""
        key1            = key
        key2            = k
        role            = v.role != null ? v.role : "external"
        vlan_split = length(regexall("-", v.vlan_range)) > 0 ? tolist(split(",", v.vlan_range)) : length(
          regexall(",", v.vlan_range)) > 0 ? tolist(split(",", v.vlan_range)
        ) : [v.vlan_range]
        vlan_range = v.vlan_range
      }
    ]
  ])

  # Loop 2 takes a list that contains a "-" or a "," and expands those values
  # into a full list.  So [1-5] becomes [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  vlan_ranges_loop_2 = {
    for k, v in local.vlan_ranges_loop_1 : "${v.key1}_${v.key2}" => {
      allocation_mode = v.allocation_mode
      description     = v.description
      key1            = v.key1
      key2            = v.key2
      role            = v.role
      vlan_list = length(regexall("(,|-)", jsonencode(v.vlan_range))) > 0 ? flatten([
        for s in v.vlan_split : length(regexall("-", s)) > 0 ? [for v in range(tonumber(
          element(split("-", s), 0)), (tonumber(element(split("-", s), 1)) + 1)
        ) : tonumber(v)] : [s]
      ]) : v.vlan_split
    }
  }

  # Loop 3 will take the vlan_list created in Loop 2 and expand this
  # out to a map of objects per vlan.

  vlan_ranges_loop_3 = flatten([
    for k, v in local.vlan_ranges_loop_2 : [
      for s in v.vlan_list : {
        allocation_mode = v.allocation_mode
        description     = v.description
        key1            = v.key1
        role            = v.role
        vlan            = s
      }
    ]
  ])

  # And lastly loop3's list is converted back to a map of objects
  vlan_ranges = { for k, v in local.vlan_ranges_loop_3 : "${v.key1}_${v.vlan}" => v }

  # End of Local Loops
}

# And lastly these values are consumed by the resources with for_each loops.

resource "aci_vlan_pool" "vlan_pools" {
  for_each    = local.vlan_pools
  alloc_mode  = each.value.allocation_mode
  description = each.value.description
  name        = each.key
  name_alias  = each.value.alias
}

resource "aci_ranges" "vlans" {
  depends_on = [
    aci_vlan_pool.vlan_pools
  ]
  for_each     = local.vlan_ranges
  description  = each.value.description
  alloc_mode   = each.value.allocation_mode
  from         = "vlan-${each.value.vlan}"
  to           = "vlan-${each.value.vlan}"
  role         = each.value.role
  vlan_pool_dn = aci_vlan_pool.vlan_pools[each.value.key1].id
}
```

I am sure someone with more experience might be able to accomplish this with fewer steps in locals but this worked for me at least.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a map with a **single key** of `access` and a list of values, then you can use ellipsis operator (`...`). Also your syntax is incorrect. Thus, the following should be used in this case:

```
  vlan_list = {
      for i in range(1, 100): 
        "access" => {
          vlan_pool   = module.vlan_pools.vlan_pool["access"]
          from        = i
          to          = i
        }...
   }
```

Comment: I am sorry to just get around to this almost a year later.  I went on to other projects.  Thank you for the thoughts